# Twitter Premium API Profile location operators profile_country: and profile_region: not working

Tags: api, twitter

I am using premium account (not sandbox) for data collection.

I want to collect:

1. All tweets **in English** that **contain ‘china’ or ‘chinese’** that are **user geolocated to US** and **not geolocated at tweet level**, **excluding all retweets**
2. All tweets **in English** that **contain ‘china’ or ‘chinese’** that are **user geolocated to ‘Minnesota’** and **not geolocated at tweet level**, **excluding all retweets**

The code is as follows:

```
premium_search_args = load_credentials('twitter_API.yaml', 
                      yaml_key ='search_tweets_premium_api', env_overwrite=False)

# keywords for the search
# key word 1
keywords = '(China OR Chinese) lang:en profile_country:US -place_country:US -is:retweet'
# key word 2
keywords = '(China OR Chinese) lang:en -place_country:US profile_region:"Minnesota" -is:retweet'

# define search rule
rule = gen_rule_payload(keywords,from_date='2019-12-01', 
       to_date='2019-12-10',results_per_call=500)

# create result stream and print before start
rs = ResultStream(rule_payload=rule, max_results=1250000, 
                  **premium_search_args)
```

My problems are that:

1. For the first one, a large portion of the results I get didn’t satisfy the query. First, some don’t have Profile Geo enrichment, i.e. user.derived.locations attribute is not in the user object. Second, if it is, a lot don’t have country code US, i.e. they are identified to other countries.
2. For the second one, the result I get from this method is a smaller subset of the results I can get from 1). That is, when I filter all tweets user geolocated to Minnesota (by user.derived.locations.region) from profile_country:US, it gives a larger sample than using profile_region:“Minnesota”. A considerable amount of data is missing using this method.

I have tried several times but it seems that user geolocation operators don’t work exactly what I want. Does anyone has any idea why this is the case? I would very much appreciate any answers/suggestions/comments.

Thank you!